# My render viewport doesnt wok

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, blender-internal-render-engine

guys, I rendered just a scratch scene with a cube, there is no problem. But with a render of my built scene, there is not possible to gain any render. I tried default setting... but still not working. what is my scene about? There is a suburb with perhaps 20 buildings made with GIS just low poly boxy ones and in the center, there is a small garden parcel with green grass and one tree. The whole scene is white with the HDR surrounding only grass is colored and the tree textured. To have leaned grass I used a wind. 
Do you have any ideas about whats going on? Thank you.

Comment: Hi. The 'blender-internal-render-engine' tag relates to the Blender Internal render engine (present in blender 2.79). Is this the render engine you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. Everybody told me to use open GL updater but, when I open blender with the default cube in the scene and hit F12 I have immediately rendered cube. My created scene at all. I can not find out what's going on. Thanks